# How to add properties to object from other arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my database I have 3 tables:

countries:

[image]

teams:

[image]

matches:

[image]

I need to display team and country names in view.

In the controller I get one match and transfer it to view:

```
    public function index() {
        $data = array();

        $q = $this->db->get('matches');
        $matches = $q->result();
        $data['matches'] = $matches;

        $this->load->view('matches/index', $data);
    }
```

I have ids country and teams but I don't know how to get names.

Should I join tables or maybe add 3 columns with names in the database?

When I try join tables:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('matches');
$this->db->join('countries', 'country.id = matches.country_id');
$this->db->join('teams', 'teams.id = matches.team_home_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

In result I have:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["country_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["league"]=> string(4) "test" ["team_home_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["team_away_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["date"]=> string(10) "15-04-2019" ["time"]=> string(5) "12:00" ["name"]=> string(5) "test1" } }
```

**name** is overwrite. Maybe my query is wrong?

If I choose the second option before adding it I must get names but I don't know-how.

In controller I have:

```
                $q = $this->db->get('countries');
                $countries = $q->result();
                $data['countries'] = $countries;

                $q = $this->db->get('teams');
                $teams = $q->result();
                $data['teams'] = $teams;

                data_match = array(
                    'country_id' => $this->input->post('country_id', true),
                    'country_name' => '',
                    'league' => $this->input->post('league', true),
                    'team_home_id' => $this->input->post('team_home_id', true),
                    'team_home_name' => '',
                    'team_away_id' => $this->input->post('team_away_id', true),
                    'team_away_name' => ''
                );
                $this->db->insert('matches', $data_match);
```

Which option will be better? Please, some tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** *"add 3 columns with names in database"* as it will violate the normalization rule.
I think using alias for each column would do the job :

```
$this->db->select('matches.*, home_team.name home_team_name, away_team.name away_team_name, country.name country_name'); // use alias for each away/home team name & country name to avoid ambiguous 'name' column
$this->db->from('matches');
$this->db->join('country', 'country.id = matches.country_id'); // changed from countries to country
$this->db->join('teams home_team', 'home_team.id = matches.team_home_id'); // use alias for the home team table
$this->db->join('teams away_team', 'away_team.id = matches.team_away_id'); // also use alias for the away team table
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I've changed the `countries` table name to `country`, you could restore it if I'm wrong.

Comment: glad I could help :)